Why pg_typeof(TIMESTAMP '2004-10-19 10:23:54+02') shows timestamp without time zone
From docs https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-DATETIME-INPUT-TIME-STAMPS

TIMESTAMP '2004-10-19 10:23:54+02'
is a timestamp with time zone

Question: Why select pg_typeof(TIMESTAMP '2004-10-19 10:23:54+02'); gives timestamp without time zone? Expecting timestamp with time zone as docs say.

Postgres version
SELECT version(); shows
PostgreSQL 14.14 (Debian 14.14-1.pgdg120+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 12.2.0-14) 12.2.0, 64-bit

As it says in that very documentation you link to:

PostgreSQL never examines the content of a literal string before determining its type, and therefore will treat both of the above as timestamp without time zone. To ensure that a literal is treated as timestamp with time zone, give it the correct explicit type:
TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE '2004-10-19 10:23:54+02'



timestamp means timestampwithOUTtime zone. That's the type you used explicitly and that's what pg_typeof() just repeated after you.
timestampTZ means timestampwithtime zone. That's what you want and that's the real pg_types.typname.
demo at db<>fiddle
select pg_typeof(timestampTZ '2004-10-19 10:23:54+02');
select pg_typeof(timestampTZ('2004-10-19 10:23:54+02'));
select pg_typeof('2004-10-19 10:23:54+02'::timestampTZ);
select pg_typeof(make_timestampTZ(2004,10,19,10,23,52,'+02'));
select pg_typeof(to_timestamp(1098174234));--no TZ in the name but it returns timestampTZ

Postgres can always clarify things like that if you ask it to explain verbose:
explain verbose select timestamp '2004-10-19 10:23:54+02';




QUERY PLAN




Result  (cost=0.00..0.01 rows=1 width=8)


Output: '2004-10-19 10:23:54'::timestamp without time zone



